# criterion for irrationality

Tags: reference-request, irrational-numbers

Given the following theorem:

> Let $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ Is there a $\delta>0$ and a rational sequence $\{p_n/q_n\}_n$ with $p_n/q_n\neq x$ and $$\left|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right|<\frac{1}{q_n^{1+\delta}}$$ for all $n$, then x is irrational.

Who did find this statement and when? Is there a proof somewhere?

Comment: Of course the crux is that the rational sequence has no repeated terms!

Answer (score 3):

I'd suspect this to be known to Liouville (as it "smells" a lot like his approximation theorem of *Comptes Rendue* **18** (1844)), but this specific observation may be even older.

The proof is simple: Assume $x=\frac ab$ is rational.
Then for any rational $\frac pq\ne x$ of a sequence as given, we have
$$\frac1{q^{1+\delta}}>\left|x-\frac pq\right|=\frac{|aq-bp|}{bq}\ge \frac 1{bq}, $$
hence
$$ q<b^{1/\delta}.$$
But with bounded denominator there are even only finitely many rationals with the weaker condition $\left|x-\frac pq\right|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

The true theorem is

**Theorem** (Liouville).-For every real algebraic number $x$ of degree  $n≥2$ exists a positive number $c (x)$ such that $| x-p / q |>\frac{ c (α)}{ q ^ n}$ holds for all rational 
$\frac pq  (q> 0)$.

By definition,  a Liouville number $x$ is such that for all $n$ large enough there is a rational
$\frac pq$ with $q\gt 1$ such that $|x- \frac pq|\le \frac{1}{q^n}$ and this such a  number $x$ is necessarily transcendental.

The theorem of Roth says that for every irrational $x$ algebraic and all $\epsilon> 0$ the inequality  $$|x-\frac pq | <\frac{1}{ q ^{2 + ε}}$$ has only a finite number of solutions in irreducible rational $\frac pq$  which implies that for all $\epsilon\gt  0$ there exists a positive constant $C (x, ε)$ such that the inequality  $| x-\frac pq |> \frac{C (x, ε)}{ q^{2 + ε}}$ is holds for all rational $\frac pq$ with $q>0$.

This is a profound theorem by which Roth won the Fields Medal (International Congress of Mathematicians, Edinburgh, 1958).

Comment: Again, the theorem mentioned by user337060 is not Liouville's one, it is just "Dirichlet irrationality criterion".  Note the difference in the exponents of the denominator (Dirichlet is $1+\delta$, whereas Liouville is $2+\delta$).

Comment: Dear friend: I feel that we are speaking a different language or it could be that there are the same names for different results or different names for the same result. I am only telling you that it may be that you confuse the substance of the matter with respect to the cardinality of the rational approximations at stake. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all, Piquito.  You have answered mentioning Liouville theorem. Your enunciation of this theorem, above,  is correct, but the correct answer to the original question is Dirichlet's rarional approximations theorem, which differs from Liouville's one in both the exponent and the order "assumption->conclusion":  Dirichlet's theorem says "If there are infinitely many distinct rationals $p/q$ such that, for some $\delta >0$, $|x-p/q| < 1/q^{1+\delta}$, then $x$ is irrational.

This is an irrationality criterion, rather than anything like "if x is irrational, then..."

Fabio M. S. Lima

P.S.: Dirichlet theorem was stated in 1842!